# php read and write file

Tags: php, function

```
function readWrite() {
    $fileReader = fopen('file.txt', 'r') or die("ERROR: File not found");
    $fileWriter = fopen('filewr.txt', 'w') or die ("ERROR: Write File not 
    found");
    $totalDaysArr= array();
    $monthNumArr= array();
    $monthArr= array();
    $row= file("file.txt");

    while($row = fgets($fileReader, 4096)) {
      list($monthNumArr[], $monthArr[], $totalDaysArr[]) = explode(",", $row);
    }

    for($x = 11; $x >= 0; $x--)
    {
      $table = explode(",", $monthNumArr[$x]);
      fwrite($fileWriter, $row[$x]);
    }
    fclose($fileWriter);
}
```

I'm a beginner at PHP, so this is what I have so far. My objective is to make a function that will read a file called file.txt and then write it in reverse using arrays. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here.

These are the requirements:

This function should use PHP array to store records (each line is a "record").

This function should use a PHP Loop to walk through the months names array and generate HTML5/CSS to display the table.

Create a function that writes the text file filewr.txt (reverse order).

This function should use PHP for loop to walk through the array in reverse order and write each array entry (line/record) to the filewr.txt file.

and also the txt file looks like this:

```
1,January,31

2,February,28

3,March,31

4,April,30

5,May,31

6,June,30

7,July,31

8,August,31

9,September,30

10,October,31

11,November,30

12,December,31
```

Comment: you forgot to mention what the problem is with your current code. It would help people to answer faster if you demonstrate the current output you get, and/or any errors you're encountering.

Comment: sorry, so its giving me an error of "undefined offset on line 56" so there's an error with my while loop but I don't know what its referring to

Comment: Line 56 doesn't help since you didn't post at least 56 lines of PHP

Comment: which line in your posted code corresponds to 56? Don't forget we can't see your whole file so we don't know.

Comment: I also tried splitting read and write into 2 different functions but that didn't work for me either

Comment: It is referring to     while($row = fgets($fileReader, 4096)) {

Comment: This looks like a CSV. If it is, why not use http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Why use `fileReader` when you decide to read the data with `file("file.txt");` in the end?
2. The writing process is quite messed up `fwrite($fileWriter, $row[$x])` is quite possibly the place where the error comes from: don't you aim to write that table to your file instead of a row from the original input file?

**Addition**

@Aureliux:
What you want to to is generating a HTML string.
Therefore, lets start with `$table='<table>'` and put this definition before the loop.
After the loop you add the tables closing tag: `$table.='</table>'`
The magic happens in between:
For each record you create the corresponding HTML representation.
`$table.='<tr><td>'.$monthNumArr.'</td><td>'.$monthArr.'</td><td>'.$totalDaysArr.'</td></tr>'`.
Finaly you move the write command after the loop and write the generated Table Markup to your output file.

What you will end up with looks like

```
function readWrite() {
    $fileWriter = fopen('filewr.txt', 'w') or die ("ERROR: Write File not 
    found");
    $totalDaysArr= array();
    $monthNumArr= array();
    $monthArr= array();
    $row= file("file.txt");

    while($row = fgets($fileReader, 4096)) {
      list($monthNumArr[], $monthArr[], $totalDaysArr[]) = explode(",", $row);
    }

    $table='<table>';
    for($x = 11; $x >= 0; $x--)
    {
      $table.='<tr><td>'.$monthNumArr.'</td><td>'.$monthArr.'</td><td>'.$totalDaysArr.'</td></tr>';
    }
    $table.='</table>';
    fwrite($fileWriter, $table);
    fclose($fileWriter);
}
```

I have no idea why you would need the reverse loop, but actually, you could achieve the same result with less effort:

```
function readWrite() {
    $row= file("file.txt");

    $table='<table>';
    for($x = 11; $x >= 0; $x--)
    {
      $table.='<tr><td>'.implode('</td><td>', explode(',',$row[$x])).'</td></tr>';
    }
    $table.='</table>';
    file_put_contents('file.txt', $table);
}
```

I did not test it. But the idea should be clear.
Personally, I would agree with @Alive to Die. His approach is the most straight forward.

Comment: What is wrong with that answer? I feel like it points to the right direction

Comment: No I agree I didn't down-vote it, so instead of $row should I use an entirely new variable?